# JDBC Table creation catch not erroring how I expect

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been building a Java app which can communicate with a local MySQL server following a guide but I have created a try statement which does successfully create the table, but I'm confused why when I re-run the command I keep getting the " table created successfully " prompt in my command line when I've stated in the SQL to create table IF it doesn't exist. Does the try statement not see the SQL error?

```
    public static void createTable() throws Exception{
    try{
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        //Create table if it does not exist
        PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS supplier(suppID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, suppName varchar(100), suppCollection varchar(100), PRIMARY KEY(suppID))");
        create.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Create Table error..");}
    finally{
        System.out.println("Table creation complete...");
    };
}
```

This isn't causing any issues with my database, I'd just like it to show the table created print line ONLY when it is actually creating the table, as in this case the table exists already so it isn't really creating a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a try/catch you should check the return value of executeUpdate():
[How to know if an sql statement executed in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326136/how-to-know-if-an-sql-statement-executed-in-java)
I think you don't get an error when the table already exists, it's just doing nothing.
If no error is thrown, your "catch"-part gets ignored.

```
if(create.executeUpdate() > 0) {
   System.out.println("Table created");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Table was not created");
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't realize you could pull the data from the executeUpdate.
Thanks!